# Accessing get_post_type inside a method of a class plugin

Tags: wordpress

I want to access get_post_type() function inside method of the class plugin. 
I also tried to get post as a global object and inserted into get_post_type as an argument:

```
class myPlugin(){

    public function my_custom_function(){
       $post_type = get_post_type(); // returns null
    }

    public function __construct() {
       $this->my_custom_function();
    }
}

new myPlugin();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `my_custom_function()` method is returning null because there's no queried post to get the post type of at the point it is run. Try delaying the loading of your class.

Change:

```
new myPlugin();
```

To:

```
function wpse_mp_load_class() {
    new myPlugin();
}
add_action( 'wp', 'wpse_mp_load_class' );
```

Comment: Thanks it worked that way but than my ajax method doesn't respond which is called with the following action:

add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_url_share_count', array($this, "get_url_share_counts_ajax"));

Comment: There wasn't enough context in your initial question to work around that. Go back to the way it was before where the class is instantiated straight away. Inside your constructor delay the method call in the same way. E.g.

`add_action( 'wp', array( $this, 'my_custom_function' ) );`